# write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor) - Error writing on a File

Tags: android, android-file

I'm working on an app that write on files every time a new data is received from a sensor (I'm receiving like 266ish float numbers per second) and I must store data from every minute, so every minute I'm creating a brand new file and write on it, sometimes, after hours I'm getting Bad file descriptor and I don't exactly know whats happening. Usually happens after at least 2:30h but it can last longer

```
    fun startMonitoring() {
        createNewFhirPackageForCurrentMonitoring {
            currentFhirPackage = it
            createNewFileManagers(it)
            shouldWriteLogFile = true
            startFhirPackageChangerRoutine()
        }
    }


  @Synchronized
    private fun createNewFileManagers(fhirPackage: FhirPackage) {
        val currentMonitoring = currentMonitoring ?: return
        val folder = filesDir
                .resolve(currentMonitoring.monitoringName)
                .resolve(fhirPackage.packageIdentifier.toString())
        dataFilesManager = BraincareDataLogFilesManager(folder)
    }
```

//here is where I change files every minute

```
private fun startFhirPackageChangerRoutine() {
        fhirPackageChangerSubscription = Observable.interval(FHIR_DURATION, FHIR_DURATION, TimeUnit.SECONDS).flatMap {
            Observable.fromCallable {
                changeFhirPackage()
            }
        }.subscribe({
        }, {
            BleLogHelper.writeError("Error on Monitoring Package Change", it)
        })
    }

 private fun changeFhirPackage() {
        val closingFhirPackage = currentFhirPackage ?: return
        val closingDataFilesManager = dataFilesManager

        createNewFhirPackageForCurrentMonitoring {
            currentFhirPackage = it
            createNewFileManagers(it)
            closingDataFilesManager?.closeOutputStreams()
        }
    }
```

//Im keep writing on a file using this function

```
private var differentialBridgeSignalOutputStream: ObjectOutputStream? = null
    fun logDifferentialBridgeSignal(signal: BraincareBluetoothDataFrame.DifferentialBridgeSignal) {
        try {
            if (differentialBridgeSignalOutputStream == null) {
                val file = File(folder, differentialBridgeSignalFileName)
                file.parentFile.mkdirs()
                file.createNewFile()

                differentialBridgeSignalOutputStream = ObjectOutputStream(FileOutputStream(file))
            }
            differentialBridgeSignalOutputStream?.writeObject(signal)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            BleLogHelper.writeError("Error writing DifferentialBridgeSignal data $signal to $differentialBridgeSignalOutputStream $e", e)
        }
    }
```

Error log

```
java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:558)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1959)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1999)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1475)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1227)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.filesmanagers.BraincareStatusLogFilesManager.logSystemInformation(BraincareStatusLogFilesManager.kt:32)
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareMonitoringService.handleStatusFrame(BraincareMonitoringService.kt:257)
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareMonitoringService.access$handleStatusFrame(BraincareMonitoringService.kt:45)
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareMonitoringService$LocalBinder$clearAndPrepareMonitoringService$2.invoke(BraincareMonitoringService.kt:158)
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareMonitoringService$LocalBinder$clearAndPrepareMonitoringService$2.invoke(BraincareMonitoringService.kt:102)
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareBluetoothManager.processFrame(BraincareBluetoothManager.kt:797)
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareBluetoothManager.handleBluetoothNotification(BraincareBluetoothManager.kt:724)
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareBluetoothManager.access$handleBluetoothNotification(BraincareBluetoothManager.kt:40)
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareBluetoothManager$startReadingSensorNotification$3.accept(BraincareBluetoothManager.kt:632)
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareBluetoothManager$startReadingSensorNotification$3.accept(BraincareBluetoothManager.kt:40)
            at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:63)
            at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:201)
            at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255)
            at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
            at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
         Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
            at libcore.io.Linux.writeBytes(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.Linux.write(Linux.java:286)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.write(BlockGuardOs.java:345)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.write(IoBridge.java:553)
            at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326) 
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1959) 
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1999) 
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1475) 
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1227) 
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347) 
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.filesmanagers.BraincareStatusLogFilesManager.logSystemInformation(BraincareStatusLogFilesManager.kt:32) 
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareMonitoringService.handleStatusFrame(BraincareMonitoringService.kt:257) 
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareMonitoringService.access$handleStatusFrame(BraincareMonitoringService.kt:45) 
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareMonitoringService$LocalBinder$clearAndPrepareMonitoringService$2.invoke(BraincareMonitoringService.kt:158) 
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareMonitoringService$LocalBinder$clearAndPrepareMonitoringService$2.invoke(BraincareMonitoringService.kt:102) 
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareBluetoothManager.processFrame(BraincareBluetoothManager.kt:797) 
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareBluetoothManager.handleBluetoothNotification(BraincareBluetoothManager.kt:724) 
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareBluetoothManager.access$handleBluetoothNotification(BraincareBluetoothManager.kt:40) 
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareBluetoothManager$startReadingSensorNotification$3.accept(BraincareBluetoothManager.kt:632) 
            at io.b4c.brain4care.modules.monitoringservice.BraincareBluetoothManager$startReadingSensorNotification$3.accept(BraincareBluetoothManager.kt:40) 
            at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:63) 
            at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:201) 
            at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:255) 
            at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66) 
            at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57) 
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

What can possibly cause this error, race conditions? It's triggering me hard because its pretty random on when its gonna happen

Comment: How did you resolved the issue? I am facing same error.